# Issue in Login with Django sqlite3 database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, authentication

I want to log in with the email that existed in the table named "user" in the sqlite3 database. Whenever I am trying to find matching the emails as given photo. The "for" loop checking only the 1st email from the table of the database. What should I do to check all the emails that existed there and then log in when both are matched. Please help me to solve it.

```
def login(request):
   form = forms.userform()
   if request.method == "POST":
          form = forms.userform(request.POST)         
          if form.is_valid():
                 email = form.cleaned_data['email'] 
                 for object in User.objects.all():
                     if object.email == email:
                      messages.success(request,'successfull login')
                      return users(request)
```

Comment: There is a `return users(request)` in your `for` loop, so it will stop after the first iteration, and return the result of `users(request)`.

Comment: the return users(request) is under the if statement. whenever I put 2nd or 3rd email from the table it does not match in this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [authenticate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) method, with this method you don't have to manually match the user with a for loop.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def login(request):
   form = forms.userform()
   if request.method == "POST":
       form = forms.userform(request.POST)         
       if form.is_valid():
           email = form.cleaned_data['email']
           password = form.cleaned_data['password']

           user = authenticate(username=username, password=password')
           if user is not None:
               messages.success(request,'successfull login')
           else:
               messages.error(request,'Invalid Credentials')

   return render(request, "home.html")
```

Comment: I have tried this one but the "user" variable is taking the superuser which was created by me for authentication. Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @Azwad Where are you trying this login ? In a browser or postman ?

Comment: @PrakashS in browser with #py manage.py runserver command

Comment: @Azwad what about other users, are they getting authenticated?

Comment: @Sumithran I have added only one superuser and that was checking in the user variable.

Comment: are you using abstractuser?

Comment: @Azwad Didn't you log out your superuser before checking other user login ?

Comment: @PrakashS I am not checking another user login. I have created a table that contains emails and I want to login with those emails in created login system.

Comment: @Sumithran no. I created superuser for admin of Database.

Comment: Show your registration form